# Active Record Observer Not Showing Changes in Staging Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, observers

I have a simple `User` model with one `Address` and a `UserObserver`. I want to run some logic in response to changes in either model. To do so, I have:

```
def before_save(user)
  if user.changes['email'] || user.try(:address).try(:changes).present?
    # run custom code
  end
end
```

When I run this code in development, it works. When I run it using `RAILS_ENV=staging`, the address changes don't appear.

```
u = User.where(email: 'foo@bar.com').first
u.address.postal_code = '44144'
u.save!  # address changes appear in observer callback in development only
```

Comment: did you set a breakpoint? My question is, does it call `before_save(user)` method in staging environment?

Comment: Hey  Fabrizio, I set up a `binding.pry` on `before_save` and it indeed does call it on staging. The `user.address.changes` is `{}`, even though when inspecting `postal_code`, the value has changed.